# Scrolling on a datagrid with ctrl button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want my datagrid to only scroll with the mouse wheel when you press the ctrl key at the same time otherwise I want to scroll the page.
I am new to wpf and mvvm which is the pattern I use in my application.

That's the page that contains the datagrid:

```
<Page x:Class="Projectname.ChapterPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
      compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Projectname" 
      xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Projectname.Core;assembly=Projectname.Core"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="900"
      Title="ChapterPage">

    <StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           Text="Kapitel"
                           Style="{StaticResource HeaderText}" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource 
                           ForegroundVeryLightBrush}"
                           FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Margin="50 -45 50 15"/>

        <Border Background="{StaticResource BlueBrush}"
                CornerRadius="10"
                Margin="10"
                MinHeight="45"
                Padding="2">

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource IconGrowButton}"
                    ToolTip="Speichern"
                    Margin="10 0"
                    MaxHeight="30"
                    MinWidth="30"
                    Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Icons/Save.png" />
                </Button>

                <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource IconGrowButton}"
                    ToolTip="Löschen"
                    MaxHeight="30"
                    MinWidth="30"
                    Margin="10 0 80 0"
                    Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Icons/Delete.png" />
                </Button>

                <Button Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource IconGrowButton}"
                    ToolTip="Zurücksetzen"
                    MaxHeight="30"
                    MinWidth="30"
                    Margin="10 0"
                    Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Icons/Reset.png" />
                </Button>

            </StackPanel>

        </Border>

        <DataGrid Margin="15 10"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters, 
                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Visibility="{Binding ChaptersVisibility, 
                      Converter={local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChapter}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

My page is loaded into a window and the scrollviewer to scroll the content is in the window.

That is the window:

```
        <Grid>

            <StackPanel>

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border Background="{StaticResource RedBrush}">
                        <Button Command="{Binding NavMenuCommand}"
                            Style="{StaticResource SystemIconButton}"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="../Images/Icons/burger- 
                                    menue.png"
                                Height="25"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>

                <local:ChapterPage
                       Padding="8 0"/>

            </StackPanel>

            <local:NavMenu Margin="0,41,628,0"/>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this but I don't want to use the xaml.cs if I can avoid it.

[The reason I want the different scrolling behavior is because there is a big user control between the data grid and the header area. Here is a picture of the division of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqOb6.png)

Comment: I edited my question. Do you understand me now?

Comment: Thank you. You then must have two `ScrollViewer`: one with the page as content and of course one with the `DataGrid` as content. By default the `ScrollViewer` with direct mouse over input receives has precedence. If the goal is to allow scrolling without the mouse over constraint, then you must handle the mouse input and scroll viewers on the common parent of both controls e.g. the containing `UserControl`. Can you please show the complete context (both scroll viewers and their parent)?

Comment: I added the code of the page and the code of the window.

Comment: Do you really want to scroll the `DataGrid` even if it's not in visible i.e. previously scrolled out of view. From a user point of view your desired behavior may not add any value. Why would he like to change his default scroll behavior  to e.g. drag the scroll bar directly or use the mouse wheel as usual? If I would use your application and wan to scroll the `DataGrid` but instead the I scroll the complete page, I would find this quite annoying and disturbing. You should leave the known and accepted/expected default behavior unless you significantly add more value to the user experience.

Comment: Actually between the border and the datagrid there is another grid that contains a usercontrol with several text boxes. That grid needs a lot of space.

Comment: You are a user yourself. Imagine you have to use an application that changes the complete interface behavior. And you  are force to learn special key combos. You would be forced to learn before you can use the application productively. You would experience this as a burden. I am sure you would drop this application in favor of a more comfortable (lower learning curve) alternative.

Comment: What would you suggest? The grid with the usercontrol with several textboxes uses up three quarters of the page. The datagrid has to share the remaining space with the header bar. I would like to scroll down the page what is already possible but in the moment you enter the datagrid the scrolling stops and thats annoying

Comment: I added a picture to explain my wish to change the scrolling behavior

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` event by the common parent of both or all participating `ScrollViewer` :

**MainWindow.xaml**
Simplified view:

```
<Window PreviewMouseWheel="HandleScroll_OnPreviewMouseWheel">
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="RootScrollViewer">
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridToScrollOnKeyPress" />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private ScrollViewer DataGridScrollViewer { get; set; }

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Find DataGrid by name (in case of multiple DataGrids)
  if (TryFindVisualChildElement(this.Root, "DataGridToScrollOnKeyPress", out DataGrid dataGrid))
  { 
    // And get its ScrollViewer (by type)
    if (TryFindVisualChildElement(dataGrid, string.Empty, out ScrollViewer scrollViewer))
    {
      this.DataGridScrollViewer = scrollViewer;
    }
  }
}

private void HandleScroll_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  // Give the main scroll viewer chance to handle its own scroll,
  // if it is the scroll source (preserve default behavior)
  if (e.Source == this.Root 
      && !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) 
      && !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
  {
    return;
  }

  e.Handled = true;
  if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
  {
    if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
      this.DataGridScrollViewer?.LineDown();
    }
    else
    {
      this.DataGridScrollViewer?.LineUp();
    }
  }
  else // Some other control is scroll source => scroll main scroll viewer
  {
    if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
      this.RootScrollViewer.LineDown();
    }
    else
    {
      this.RootScrollViewer.LineUp();
    }
  }
}

// If the 'childElementName' parameter is NULL, an empty string or whitespace it will be ignored (only the type will be relevant)
public bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, string childElementName, out TChild childElement)
  where TChild : FrameworkElement
{
  childElement = null;
  if (parent == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
  {
    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
    if (child is TChild resultElement 
        && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(childElementName) || resultElement.Name.Equals(childElementName, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
    {
      childElement = resultElement;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindVisualChildElement(child, childElementName, out childElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: The scroll viewer of the content and the datagrid are not in the same xaml. How can I get it?

Comment: You use the TryFindVisualChildElement method. See the above code and replace the parent (in the example it's  DataGridToScrollOnKeyPress) with the main scroll viewer instance. This should find the DataGrid and drill down to the ScrollViewer.

Comment: I have updated the example ( `OnLoaded()` and  `TryFindVisualChildElement()`). You only have to adjust the name of the `DataGrid` .

Comment: When I try to get the scrollviewer from the datagrid it returns null. After some debugging I found out that VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid, i) returns 0

Comment: It is important that the `DatGrid` is loaded before you can access its visual tree. You can make the `DataGridScrollViewer` property `static`. Then attach a `Loaded` event handler to the `DataGrid` and use the `TryFindVisualChildElement` from above to get the `ScrollViewer` and assign it to the static `DataGridScrollViewer`. Better add a NULL check in `HandleScroll_OnPreviewMouseWheel` before accessing the `DataGridScrollViewer`: e.g., `DataGridScrollViewer?..LineDown();`